# Como resolver: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estou com um problema em uma aplicação usando ES6. Estou criando uma tabela que recebe valores de um formulário, mas sempre que clico no botão para enviar as informações para a tabela, da o seguinte erro.

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar.

Código que dá o erro:

```
 var campos = [
    document.querySelector('#data'),
    document.querySelector('#quantidade'),
    document.querySelector('#valor')
];

console.log(campos);

var tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');

document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

   campos.forEach(function (campo) {
       var td = document.createElement('td');
       td.textContent = campo.value;
       td.append('td');
       td.appendChild(td);
       // td.appendChild('td');
       // td.appendChild(td);
   });

   var tdVolume = document.createElement('td');
   tdVolume.textContent = campos[1].value * campos[2].value;

   tr.appendChild(tdVolume);

   tbody.appendChild(tr);

   campos[0].value = '';
   campos[1].value = 1;
   campos[2].value = 0;

   campos[0].focus();

});
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema esteja aqui: `var tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');`. Vc verificou se algum elemento foi atribuido a variável `tdbody`? Confira com um `console.log` nela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que esteja tentando inserir o td dentro dele mesmo.
No código abaixo alterei para inserir o td no tr.
Veja se resolve seu problema.

```
campos.forEach(function (campo) {
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   td.textContent = campo.value;
   td.append('td');
   tr.appendChild(td);
});
```